# time.clock() and time.sleep() in Google App engine flex env

Tags: python-2.7, time

In my App Engine Flex project  I have created a very simple flask endpoint which calls `time.clock()` and `time.sleep()`.

here is the code

```
@app.route('/api/time')
def measure_time():
    t1 = time.clock()
    time.sleep(5)
    t2 = time.clock()
    time.sleep(10)
    t3 = time.clock()
```

Then I return the values of those variables and this what I get

```
t1: 51.122765   
t2: 51.12284    
t3: 51.127062  
t2-t1: 7.49999999954e-05    
t3-t2: 0.00422200000001  
t3-t1: 0.004297
```

Clearly it does not sleep for 5 nor 10 seconds.

Is this a special behaviour of App Engine Flex ? Or something I don't understand with Python (2.7) ?

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, `time.clock()` returns the current processor time (CPU time spent on the current thread), not the clock time.  You want `time.time()`